# Collapsing and displaying of divs is reverted all at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery on a prototype for a web application which shall be used on iPad.
I have programmed a test page, which have two divs: one for input fields and the other for displaying a help file (in my case a PDF).
After the page was started, the first div is displayed and the second collapsed.
Above the div-tags i got a button.
When i start the page for the first time and click on that button, i want to collapse the div with the input fields and show the other div with the help file.
Next time i click on the button i want to show the div with the input fields again and collapse the div with the help file.
But when i click the button after starting my test page, the first div (with id "content") is collapsed and the help-div displayed for the fraction of a second and the the original state of the page is restored.

Can anybody help me please?

Here's the HTML i'm using:

```
<form style="position:relative; height:100%; width:100%; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="load_help" style="font-weight:bold; margin:5px; float:right;">i</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="content" style="height:300px; width:500px; background-color:yellow; display:block;">
                    <label style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px; text-align:left; border-left-style:none; border-left-width:unset; border-top-style:none; border-top-width:unset; border-right-style:none; border-right-width:unset; border-bottom-style:none; border-bottom-width:unset; height:auto; width:auto; word-wrap:normal; overflow:auto;">Test page</label>
                    <label style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:20px; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; text-align:left; border-left-style:none; border-left-width:unset; border-top-style:none; border-top-width:unset; border-right-style:none; border-right-width:unset; border-bottom-style:none; border-bottom-width:unset; height:auto; width:auto; word-wrap:normal; overflow:auto;">Label 1</label>
                    <label style="position:absolute; top:90px; left:20px; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; text-align:left; border-left-style:none; border-left-width:unset; border-top-style:none; border-top-width:unset; border-right-style:none; border-right-width:unset; border-bottom-style:none; border-bottom-width:unset; height:auto; width:auto; word-wrap:normal; overflow:auto;">Label 2</label>
                    <label style="position:absolute; top:130px; left:20px; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; text-align:left; border-left-style:none; border-left-width:unset; border-top-style:none; border-top-width:unset; border-right-style:none; border-right-width:unset; border-bottom-style:none; border-bottom-width:unset; height:auto; width:auto; word-wrap:normal; overflow:auto;">Label 3</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="help" style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:aqua; display:none;">
                    <object type="application/pdf" data="../HelpDocuments/MyPdf.pdf" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></object>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="../scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#load_help").click(function () {
                    var contentElement = document.getElementById("content");
                    var helpElement = document.getElementById("help");
                    if (contentElement.style.display == "block") {
                        contentElement.style.display = "none";
                        helpElement.style.display = "block";
                    }
                    else {
                        contentElement.style.display = "block";
                        helpElement.style.display = "none";
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are "submitting" the form when you click the button, you need to prevent that event like this:

```
e.preventDefault()
```

You can also type your button as a button to prevent submit like this:

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#load_help").click(function(e) {
    var contentElement = document.getElementById("content");
    var helpElement = document.getElementById("help");
    if (contentElement.style.display == "block") {
      contentElement.style.display = "none";
      helpElement.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      contentElement.style.display = "block";
      helpElement.style.display = "none";
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form style="position:relative; height:100%; width:100%; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button id="load_help" style="font-weight:bold; margin:5px; float:right;">i</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="content" style="height:300px; width:500px; background-color:yellow; display:block;">
          <label style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px; text-align:left; border-left-style:none; border-left-width:unset; border-top-style:none; border-top-width:unset; border-right-style:none; border-right-width:unset; border-bottom-style:none; border-bottom-width:unset; height:auto; width:auto; word-wrap:normal; overflow:auto;">Test page</label>
          <label style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:20px; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; text-align:left; border-left-style:none; border-left-width:unset; border-top-style:none; border-top-width:unset; border-right-style:none; border-right-width:unset; border-bottom-style:none; border-bottom-width:unset; height:auto; width:auto; word-wrap:normal; overflow:auto;">Label 1</label>
          <label style="position:absolute; top:90px; left:20px; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; text-align:left; border-left-style:none; border-left-width:unset; border-top-style:none; border-top-width:unset; border-right-style:none; border-right-width:unset; border-bottom-style:none; border-bottom-width:unset; height:auto; width:auto; word-wrap:normal; overflow:auto;">Label 2</label>
          <label style="position:absolute; top:130px; left:20px; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; text-align:left; border-left-style:none; border-left-width:unset; border-top-style:none; border-top-width:unset; border-right-style:none; border-right-width:unset; border-bottom-style:none; border-bottom-width:unset; height:auto; width:auto; word-wrap:normal; overflow:auto;">Label 3</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="help" style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:aqua; display:none;">
          <object type="application/pdf" data="../HelpDocuments/MyPdf.pdf" width="500px" height="500px"></object>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


</form>
```

Comment: Thank You Zorken17! You are right. Thank You for Your help.

Comment: You are welcome! If you like my answer please mark it as one and if you want also give it a bump up.